# DB2 Casting Clob to Varchar to Integer

Tags: sql, casting, db2, varchar, substr

I have a function

```
REPLACE((SELECT VARCHAR(SUBSTR(CAST(THE_NOTE AS VARCHAR(32000)), LOCATE('Line Haul Charge', CAST(THE_NOTE AS VARCHAR(32000))) + 18),7)   
FROM NOTES WHERE PROG_TABLE = 'TLORDER' AND ID_KEY = CAST (TLORDER.DETAIL_LINE_ID AS VARCHAR(7)) AND NOTE_TYPE = 'O'),' ','') AS LINE_HAUL_CHARGE
```

That converts a CLOB to a varchar and returns a number value (including a decimal)

from here I need to cast it as an integer data type; however I receive an error that reads

```
Invalid character found in a character string argument of the function "BIGINT"/"INTEGER"/"DOUBLE"
```

even if I couldn't convert it to a number data type I need to use this field to subtract from another `VARCHAR` data field, but when I do I receive the error

```
Field '6' is of an unsupported type
```

Even after removing the decimals I still receive the error above,

how can I use this field to subtract from another field ?

Comment: Well obviously you cannot convert a string that contains a `.` (dot) character  to an integer value. What's your question?

Comment: I used the function replace to set the "." to a blank space and still got the error.